Using arrays from different classes in java
I am making a TicTacToe game. The idea is I print a 3x3 grid with numbers from 1-9 and when a player selects a number it changes that element in the grid array with a character like * or o
I'm facing an issue with modifying elements of a 2D array in Java. Here's a simplified version of my code:
I have a Board class that initializes a grid array and a Move class responsible for prompting players to make moves and updating the grid accordingly. However, despite calling the storeMove method in the Move class, the grid array doesn't seem to reflect any changes made within storeMove.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
public class Board {
    public char[][] grid;

    public Board(int rows, int cols) {
        grid = new char[rows][cols];
        initializeGrid();
    }

    private void initializeGrid() {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = (char) (count + '0');
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

public class Move {
    public int playerMove;

    public void promptPlayer(String player, Board board) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Select a tile: ");
        playerMove = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");
        storeMove(playerMove, player, board.grid);
    }

    private void storeMove(int playerMove, String player, char[][] grid) {
        // Convert playerMove to a character
        char moveChar = (char) (playerMove + '0');

        // Check if the moveChar is between '1' and '9'
        if (moveChar >= '1' && moveChar <= '9') {
            // Determine the symbol based on the player
            char symbol = player.equals("player1") ? '*' : 'o';

            // Iterate through the grid to find and replace the character
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                    if (grid[i][j] == moveChar) {
                        grid[i][j] = symbol;
                        return; // Exit once the move is made
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid move. Please enter a number between 1 and 9.");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board(3, 3);
        Move move = new Move();

        // Print initial grid
        System.out.println("Initial grid:");
        printGrid(board.getGrid());

        // Prompt player to make moves
        move.promptPlayer("player1", board);
        move.promptPlayer("player2", board);

        // Print grid after moves
        System.out.println("Grid after moves:");
        printGrid(board.getGrid());
    }

    public static void printGrid(char[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

In this setup, despite calling storeMove in the Move class, the changes made to grid within storeMove do not persist when accessed later in the Main class. I suspect the issue might be related to how Java handles arrays or references within methods.
Any insights or suggestions on why the grid array isn't being updated would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

By the way, Are arrays passed by value or passed by reference in Java?

Your code works for me (after adding missing method getGrid to class Board).

Give example input that fails.

better include a [mre] , the missing code can be part of the problem - like accessing grid directly and sometimes using getGrid(). (sidenote: you do not need int for count; you can do calculations directly with char like in char count = '1'; and count++; {used original name to make it clear})

Given that the code you provided is incomplete, the issue might arise when you try to fetch the grid from the Board class. Your getter might not be returning the reference to the grid properly.
public char[][] getGrid(){
    return this.grid;
}

You can try adding the above getter to your Board class and then recompile your code.
I just ran it and got the expected behavior after adding this piece.
